# Graphviz on Sphinx generates really tall graphs when running on Alpine

Tags: svg, python-sphinx, graphviz, alpine-linux

Using the extension `sphinx.ext.graphviz` on Sphinx, the generated graphs are extremely tall (×3700 the expected height), when executing Sphinx on a CI.

The problem is on the generated images, as can be seen inspecting the generated SVGs:

Locally generated:

```
<svg width="424pt" height="1029pt"
 viewBox="0.00 0.00 423.88 1029.00"
```

CI generated:

```
<svg width="505pt" height="3822670pt"
 viewBox="0.00 0.00 505.23 3822669.58"
```

Changing Graphviz version, Sphinx version, even base image versions did not help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was Alpine. I did not find any specific mentions to this behavior of GraphViz on Alpine, but [Python's official image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) has this to offer on Alpine:

> The main caveat to note is that it does use musl libc instead of glibc and friends, so software will often run into issues depending on the depth of their libc requirements/assumptions.

Changing the base image to Debian (`python:3.12-bullseye`) fixed the problem.